# Cast a variable as a function/method pointer in Dart? (Delegate?)

Tags: function, methods, casting, dart

Say I have a Map type that stores functions/methods inside of it, like so:

```dart
Map triggerHandler = {
  'x' : (t) => hello(t)
};
```

Now, what I want to do next is to declare that the Type of these Map values are to be functions.

I can always do this:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> triggerHandler = {
  'x' : (t) => hello(t)
};
```

But this doesn't help stop programmers from putting in non-functions into the Map values. 'x' could then be a String, or an Integer.

The reason I want to do this is because I have a function that needs to only accept Maps with functions as the values. Calling the array key of 'x' is done by triggerHandlerx when it is a function, rather than triggerHandler[x]. I haven't tested if this causes an error to occur or not, but this doesn't seem semantically correct to me.

It would seem that the most logical way to do this would be to set the Type for the value as a function. Such as giving a Map a type casted value of 'delegate':

```dart
Map<String, delegate> triggerHandler = { // Note, this won't work
  'x' : (t) => hello(t)
};
```

What is the correct way to do this in Dart? (If there is a way)
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Function` as type or if you also want to specify the arguments and return type of these functions you can create typedefs.

```dart
Map<String, Function> triggerHandler = {
  'x' : (t) => hello(t)
};
```

```dart
typedef int SomeName(SomeType arg1);

Map<String, SomeName> triggerHandler = {
  'x' : (t) => hello(t)
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Can't believe I've not come across this before, heard of them, but never knew what they did. I'll test tomorrow, thank you! (P.S. I've noticed when you edit my posts you can put the correct colour coding on? I would private message if I knew how to, but how do you do this? Is it worth starting a topic/question on itself? Cheers)

Comment: Glad to hear this is what you were looking for. If the answer solves your problem you should accept the answer so everyone sees it is solved using the checkmark below the upvote buttons, thanks.

Comment: You can add the code coloring yourself by putting `<!-- language-all: lang-dart --> somewhere in your question/answer. If you forget the syntax, hit the edit button on one of your previous questions and you can see it there.